# Uploading media to twitter fails

Tags: twitter, upload, media

I am using upload media through twitter API

https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json
it’s showing success when uploading image

```
{“media_id”:1126023933537292288,“media_id_string”:“1126023933537292288”,“size”:108365,“expires_after_secs”:86400,“image”:{“image_type”:“image/jpeg”,“w”:752,“h”:960}}
```

but

https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=STATUS&media_id=1126023933537292288

giving me

```
{
“request”: “/1.1/media/upload.json”,
“error”: “Invalid mediaId.”
}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If the upload didn't return an error message, it should be available to use. As [answered here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary.html), the `STATUS` command is only necessary for video uploads.

> You should only call STATUS command if FINALIZE response contains `processing_info` field